# Twitter List Tweets and Delicious Links as Posts

Tags: plugins, posts, categories, twitter

I'm trying to integrate Tweets from a Twitter list as individual posts categorized as "Twitter," and trying to do the same thing from a Delicious account.

I've found several plugins that will add Tweets as a post from a specific user, but have been unable to find one that does it based on a list on Twitter, nor with Delicious. Anyone have any experience (or can point me toward a plugin that will do either tasks)?'

The ultimate goal is to show relevant tweets and delicious links for a given post (or page), and have a random sampling of both the tweets and delicious links on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Twitter API`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) to get all the status updates by user and write a function to store it in database. Or there's a nice plugin ( [Twitter Tools](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-tools/) ) which saves all your tweets as a blog post.

> #### A Quote from plugins description -
>
> - Archive your Twitter tweets (downloaded every 10 minutes)
> - Create a blog post from each of your tweets

Comment: Unfortunately, just going the API route is a little beyond my skill set.

Comment: I checked out Twitter Tools, installed it, despite being a little leery of the fact it hadn't been updated in 2+ years. Unfortunately, that doesn't fit my criteria. It only allows tweets as posts from a given user, rather than a Twitter list.